# How to prevent solder getting into through hole during HASL process?

Tags: manufacturing, documentation, manufacturing-process

I think this is an easy enough question - I just don't know how to effectively search for the answer.

I have a PCB that came back and the programming header is plugged with solder. This most likely happened during the HASL process.

I thought about tenting the holes, but that would require me to break the tent when I want to program my boards and that seems like extra work that I'd rather not do.

What can I do on the PCB or documentation (specifically the wording / language) to the fabrication house to prevent it from happening ?

Comment: How small is this programming header that it got plugged with solder? That kinda sounds more like bad quality control at the PCB fab. Is this a production PCB service or a hobbiest PCB service? BTW, the assembly house is the place that mounts components onto the PCB, not the guys who fabricate the PCB. That's the PCB fab.

Comment: @Toor in fairness it is small  - 31 mil (0.787mm). Gah yes you are right - my mistake about assembly house vs fab house.

Comment: I'd talk to the PCB house about the issue. Maybe there is a HASL thickness that can be specfiied and they just use a default if you don't tell them any better.

Comment: @Toor which maybe the key to this. We didn't tell them this, so they may have very well used some default value.

Comment: Let us know if HASL thickness is something that can be specified (it might not be since it's hot air knives that are used, I don't know).

Comment: Obviously discuss with fab house. As far as future actions go, you can add a note to the fab drawing saying that holes must be open. You can also modify the design to use an SMT header. Usually fab houses read the notes on the fab drawing prior to quoting. "NOTE: holes on Header J2 must be free of obstrucion after HASL finishing."

Comment: If we're talking about alternative programming headers, connectorless programming headers are AMAZING. The only brand I know is Tag-Connect but there must be others.

Comment: @Toor my colleauge is not so keen to change.

Comment: I have used Tag Connect also. They work great, BUT I don't think they will work well with HASL. I am using them with ENIG boards. HASL creates convex surface for pins to touch, and also there is typically a residue or thin film of oxidation or something that makes for unreliable connection to pogo pins. Maybe HASL followed by some type of cleaning operation will work.

Comment: I was also going to suggest to change to ENIG.

Comment: I use my Tag Connects with HASL. Works fine so far. But maybe your boards are older and have been through more than mine.

Comment: @Ale..chenski ENIG is a bit more expensive (I don't know by how much) but its a 2 layer board and its a very cost sensitive project.From what I have read, at 4L the price between HASL and ENIG start to balance out - but I could be wrong about that.

Comment: HASL is absolutely ugly for small SMT components, solder bumps prevent parts from proper leveling, especially for hand soldering. Some batches have very bad "leveling". Sometimes I had to wick out the entire board before soldering.

Comment: How small is small? 0603? 0402? 0201?

Comment: @Toor, OK, that is good to know about tag connect working with HASL. My experience is more based on PCB test. I have found that any component pads used as pogo pin test pads should be free of solder, otherwise the pogo pins don't make good contact. But running a board through SMT with paste on the pad is not the same as HASL, I guess. This is also more of a mass production thing. A little bit of something transfers to the pogo pin each time a board goes through the fixture. After a while, the pins get covered with goo and don't make contact anymore, and you start getting bogus test failures.